# Reload javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a webapp that onload it runs the my javascript variables, and one of the the variable is a javascript weeknumber function in which it reads and display properly.  But the problem is that the webapp does not refresh the variable unless i reload app (which i don't want to do) so i was hoping there was a way to create to create the weeknumber  script into a function in which i call (similiar to `getdate()` instead of it running when the webapp loads. here is the script i have been using

```
<script>
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() - 1) / 7);
}
var week = "Week "
var weekNumber = week+(new Date()).getWeek();

</script>
```

Comment: You can always wrap what you're using to get `weekNumber` into a function and call it wherever you want instead of the function, can't you?

Comment: Sure, you can put any code inside a function. Do you have any particular problem with that? It looks you already know how to define a function. If you need more information, have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html to learn more about functions.

Comment: "so i was hoping there was a way to create to create the weeknumber script into a function in which i call (similiar to getdate()" - are you asking how to write a function? If not, could you give more of an explanation of what you're trying to achieve and why it's not working the way you expect?

Comment: The code you posted has the effect of modifying the Date prototype, but it doesn't actually do anything else to the DOM. What is it that you expect updating that `weekNumber` variable to actually do?

Comment: i need the weeknumber to update accordingly to the weeknum change, the webapp screen if loaded on a screen will show which ever week it is, but when the week changes the weeknum doesn't unless you refresh browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your webapp framework is, there may be an event you can use to trigger the update. If not you can use `setInterval()`.

```
<script>
    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() - 1) / 7);
    }
    var week = "Week "
    var date = new Date()
    var weekNumber = week + date.getWeek();

    function setWeek() {
        date = new Date()
        weekNumber = week + date.getWeek();
    }

    setInterval(setWeek, 500) // Sets the week variable every 500 milliseconds

</script>
```

Here the `week` variable is made global, and the `setInterval` calls the `setWeek()` function every 500 milliseconds to update the global variable.

Comment: so if i understand, the script will reload every 500 ms, if so that is exactly what i was hoping for but better